# Regex pattern causing syntax error when pasted into preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex

I have used the online regex tester http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to come up with the following pattern: ( I've pasted all three lines as I'm not sure if i should be pasting the Regexp or the pattern.)

```
RegExp: /<div class="label">.*?<h3>(.*?)</h3>.*?"more">(.*?)\|/g
pattern: <div class="label">.*?<h3>(.*?)</h3>.*?"more">(.*?)\|
flags: g
```

If I use it in php like this:

```
$pattern = '/<div class="label">.*?<h3>(.*?)</h3>.*?"more">(.*?)\|/g';

preg_match_all($pattern,$page,$matches );
```

I get an error:

> Warning: preg_match_all()
>   [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown
>   modifier '.' in ...

Can someone please explain how I can get my regex from this tool, into the correct format for use in PHP. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're not escaping the slash in `</h3>` and `g` means apply globally, that's not needed here since you're using `preg_match_all`, and it's not a valid [modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in PHP's implementation of regex, just omit it

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/<div class="label">.*?<h3>(.*?)<\/h3>.*?"more">(.*?)\|/';
```

Comment: A common alternative is to use some uncommon character like `#` as regex delimiter, as for example in `#r?eg*ex#i` - which is often useful to avoid extraneous escaping.

Comment: my goodness that was fast! however with your pattern I get:
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'g' in...

Comment: @Pickledegg: ah right, `g` means apply globally, that's not needed here since you're using `preg_match_all`, and it's not a valid modifier in PHP, just omit it (answer edited to reflect change).

Comment: Three simple words:
BEST.
FORUM.
EVER.
Thanks a million to the power of a million guys.